# how to add New device for testing and make a new certificate for testing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a exiting certificate for testing on device but i have added a new device for testing so how may create a new provisioning so that i can test the app on new device also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to follow instruction for add new device for testing:

This worked for me:

1. Login to your iphone provisioning portal through [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)
2. Add the UDID in your iphone device Go back to XCode, open up the Organizer and
3. select "Provisioning Profiles", ensure that "Automatic Device
           Provisioning" is checked on the top right pane, then click on the
           "Refresh" button, and magically all your devices set in the
           provisioning portal will be automatically added.

Thanks...!

Comment: Listen i have already a provisioning profile on whici i am testing on iPhone i have new device i have added that in developer now i have to make a new provisoning or not for testing on it

Comment: if your phone connected in xcode show's your iphone name in simulator selection option?

Comment: my device is not connected to mac i have made new provioning profile how to save it on mac in which folder

Answer (score 12):

If you need to add a testing device, you should go to **developer.apple.com** -> **Member Center** -> **iOS Provisioning Portal** -> Select **Devices** on the left tab menu-> Press **Add Device** button -> insert test device UDID and save this new device.

After that you need to go to **Provisioning** section (on the left tab menu) and create new or edit existing development and distribution provisioning profiles. After that download new development and distribution provisioning profiles on your development Mac, add this profiles in Xcode Organizer to your test devices (iPhones of iPods) and update Target settings of your application project for Code signing (Select your **Target** -> **Build Settings** -> **Code signing Identity** option).

Thats all - now you can run your app on test devices. I would also recommend you to look at [TestFlight](http://testflight.com) service, which can provide you a useful way of over-the-air application builds distribution.

Hope that will help you! :)